# Unable to refresh BlazorWASM application after changes in .net 5/no hot-reload in .net 6

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I am seeing some odd behaviour in VS2019 (and also identically in VS2019 preview and VS2022 preview, and running either .net 5 or .net 6 preview):

If I create the standard empty Blazor client (only) project and run it, any changes made to the razor files subsequently are not reflected in the running project in any form (even after saving and refreshing the browser).

Creating a 'dotnet.exe watch run' profile works as expected on file save, but the 'Apply Code Changes' button in .net 6 VS2019 preview and VS2022 does nothing with either profile.

The one suspicious observation I have is that the terminal in which the server is run displays:

```
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\microDevBox\source\repos\IMS36\IMS36
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\microDevBox\source\repos\IMS36\IMS36
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:59707
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I seem to be getting both a Development and Production environment?

This is 100% reproducible across all three versions of VS each time I create a blank project.

Any insights gratefully received!

Comment: I believe hot reload of .razor pages is not supported yet.  It will become available not later than .NET6 production release.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/

Comment: Hi thanks @JasonD, this does seem to be the case (though this can be achieved with 'dotnet watch run' if not debugging).  I guess MS are working on unifying all the hot reloads in the final release of .net 6

Comment: Blazor train video recently shows this working (blazor and .net 6 preview) but I cannot replicate on my own machine - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwsokSqd964